# Any basic C++ websites/ book using visual studio 2008 enviroment?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am looking for websites/books which teach C++ in visual studio 2008
THanks

Comment: There's not the slightest need to tie perfectly good language teaching material to a particular version of a particular IDE that only works on a particular platform. A good C++ book and some other resource for the little you need to know to get started with the IDE (even a two pages online tutorial can contain everything you'll need in the next months) should be a better combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C++ using Visual Studio, the obvious site would be MSDN itself. Go through these:

- [Visual C++ Walkthroughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w9eycd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [Getting Started with Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdbe067e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [Introducing the Visual Studio IDE (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384847%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Please see

- [**The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
- [**List of freely available programming books**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

Also, Visual Studio is only an environment that you use to program in. You can read any book on C++.